# Import namespace - Cannot resolve the name to a(n) 'type definition' component

Tags: maven, xsd, jaxb, xjc

Context: I am generating java classes from xsd files using maven-jaxb plugin. All my .xsd files are in a single location - src/main/resource directory.

Problem: Everything works fine when xsd's don't reference/import other xsd's with a different target namespace. However when the following xsd below (with targetNamespace="http://www.companyA.com/someservice") imports another xsd filename.xsd from a different namespace (namespace="http://www.companyB.com/"), I get the above error: Cannot resolve the name xxx to a(n) 'type definition' component.

Edit: the element name in the current xsd file is 'entityName', and its type is "companyB:entityName" (i.e.) the names are the same.

I then tried invoking xjc on this file from the command line and this generated Java classes correctly. I also made sure that in Eclipse, I am able to ctrl-click/examine source on "type="companyCdm:entityName", which correctly opens the filename.xsd file. However for some reason maven is unable to get to it.

Question: What am I missing? Why is this case (2 namespaces) different from dealing with a single namespace?

Here is my XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.companyA.com/someservice"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:companyB="http://www.companyB.com/version"
    targetNamespace="http://www.companyA.com/someservice"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.companyB.com/version" schemaLocation="filename.xsd" />

    <xsd:element name="MyName" type="MyType" />

    <xsd:complexType name="MyType">
        <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            A list
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="entityName" type="companyB:entityName" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error except my main xsd is in the dir I'm running the command and the xsd's i'm depending on are already in an other (sub) directory.  Any suggestions?

Comment: none at this point, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm facing the exactly same issue. Do you have any solution now ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured out the work-around:

I moved all the dependent xsd's (that the problematic xsd's references) plus a bunch of other un-used xsds to a separate folder and then re-generated code using maven - it works now. It appears that there was some namespace conflict with one of the other un-used xsd's  i haven't yet pointed out the specific one.

Answer (score 0):

The O'Rielly `[Java and XML Chap3][1]` says that using an InputSource will enable you to parse relative paths:

Comment: here is the link: http://books.google.com/books?id=W63YTzab8gkC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=%22java+and+xml%22+inputsource+sax+parser+chapter+3&source=bl&ots=GQl41zC-CE&sig=p1treNnjJVWvPTI21TLP9v-FrW0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A5InUt3FHajc2QX2o4HYDg&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22java%20and%20xml%22%20inputsource%20sax%20parser%20chapter%203&f=false